# What is the ideal way to terminate a java subprocess? process.destroyForcibly() doesn't terminate my process

Tags: java, swing, process, terminate

I have a Java Swing application which creates a subprocess. The main Swing application has a stop button which when hit should terminate the subprocess immediately. "process.destroy()" didn't work.

```
Process myProcess = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-classpath", System.getProperty("java.class.path"), "MyClass.java");
try {
    myProcess.waitFor();
} 
catch (Exception e) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

...

```
myStopButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        myProcess.destroyForcibly(); 
        // myProcess is a really long and complex process. So I could not destroy that using process.destroyForcibly().
    }
}
```

1. Can I send some signal to the subprocess to call System.exit()
   internally?
2. Can I use "taskkill" to kill the sub process ONLY?

Comment: Could you please show us how you start the subprocess and how you try to suspend it…

Comment: If you have *not* working code, please provide a [mcve], otherwise we can't help you. Beyond that, stopping processes is a solved, well documented topic. So: please do solid research prior posting questions here.

Comment: And then: System.exit() kills your JVM, including all subprocesses. But also the parent one, so that is not what you intend to use (most of the time).

Comment: If I call System.exit() inside the new process, why would that stop the main process?

Comment: I had to post this question since most of the solutions didn't work for me. For instance, see the java documentation for destory():
"Kills the process. Whether the process represented by this Process object is normally terminated or not is implementation dependent."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It really depends on your java version.

**Prior to Java 8**

```
public abstract void destroy()
```

> Kills the subprocess. The subprocess represented by this Process
>   object is forcibly terminated.

Java 8

```
public abstract void destroy()
```

> Kills the subprocess. Whether the subprocess represented by this
>   Process object is forcibly terminated or not is implementation
>   dependent.

```
public Process destroyForcibly()
```

> Kills the subprocess. The subprocess represented by this Process
>   object is forcibly terminated. The default implementation of this
>   method invokes destroy() and so may not forcibly terminate the
>   process. Concrete implementations of this class are strongly
>   encouraged to override this method with a compliant implementation.
>   Invoking this method on Process objects returned by
>   ProcessBuilder.start() and Runtime.exec(java.lang.String) will
>   forcibly terminate the process.
>
> Note: The subprocess may not terminate immediately. i.e. isAlive() may
>   return true for a brief period after destroyForcibly() is called. This
>   method may be chained to waitFor() if needed.
>
> Returns: the Process object representing the subprocess to be forcibly
>   destroyed.

**Java 9**

```
public abstract void destroy​()
```

> Kills the process. Whether the process represented by this Process
>   object is normally terminated or not is implementation dependent.
>   Forcible process destruction is defined as the immediate termination
>   of a process, whereas normal termination allows the process to shut
>   down cleanly. If the process is not alive, no action is taken. The
>   CompletableFuture from onExit() is completed when the process has
>   terminated.

```
public Process destroyForcibly​()
```

> Kills the process forcibly. The process represented by this Process
>   object is forcibly terminated. Forcible process destruction is defined
>   as the immediate termination of a process, whereas normal termination
>   allows the process to shut down cleanly. If the process is not alive,
>   no action is taken. The CompletableFuture from onExit() is completed
>   when the process has terminated.
>
> Invoking this method on Process objects returned by
>   ProcessBuilder.start() and Runtime.exec(java.lang.String) forcibly
>   terminate the process.

API Note:

> The process may not terminate immediately. i.e. isAlive() may return
>   true for a brief period after destroyForcibly() is called. This method
>   may be chained to waitFor() if needed. Implementation Requirements:
>   The default implementation of this method invokes destroy() and so may
>   not forcibly terminate the process. Implementation Note: Concrete
>   implementations of this class are strongly encouraged to override this
>   method with a compliant implementation.

Returns:

> the Process object representing the process forcibly destroyed

Comment: Nice comprehensive list ;-)